# Script that destroys objects on touch C# for Unity does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script that destroys objects on touch in C# for Unity, but it doesn't work.

This is the code - if any could help using UnityEngine;

```
public class DestroyOnCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting `gameObject` using the Unity Editor?

Comment: Please share more code and information. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Have you add any collider component on your object? Can you please share a screenshot of your inspector that includes the components of your gameobject through Unity's editor

Comment: Make sure your gameObject has a collider set as trigger and probably a rigidbody so that collision can take place. Try to create a ray on touch if you don't have one and use that to check for collision.

Comment: which object is the script on..

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to destroy the GameObject that touched the GameObject with this script then you need to use collision.gameObject as just gameObject refers to the one attached to the script.

Another possible is that, if you are in unity2d then you need to use OnCollisonEnter2D()

Additionally make sure that both GameObjects have colliders attached and that at least one of them has a non static rigidbody, as collisions will not register without one.